# What is the long version of ={0} in C?

Tags: c

I have been asked this question:

> `= { 0 }` is a "shortcut" for what longer code?

So after many searches and rummaging through my C book I know everything that it does with aggregate initialization but  what if I wanted to write the longer version of this code. Here is the actual code from the program just in case

```
static char vid[25][100] = { 0 } ;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/201101/139010

Comment: Set all slots to `0`.

Comment: The example you're showing is redundant. static linkage as shown defaults to zero-initialized anyway, so it is somewhat pointless.

Comment: The appropriate response: "How much longer do you want it?"

Comment: @MichaelBurr LOL!Indeed,one can make it as bloated as one wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The long version is a loop that initializes all of the members of the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
{
    myArray[i] = 0;
}
```

The compiler will probably generate a call to the `memset` function, which may or may not contain a more optimized version of this naive loop.

But like Dietrich points out, in the example you've shown in the question, you're declaring a `static` array. That makes things a bit more complicated. Uninitialized static data is placed in a special section of the executable called the `.bss` section and is required by both the C and C++ standards to be default-initialized to zero. If you explicitly initialize the data, the linker puts it in the `.data` section of the executable. Explicitly initializing to 0 is a bit of a special case. Smart linkers will omit the explicit initializer and place the data in the `.bss` section. Dumb linkers may still place the data in the `.data` section. So it's probably better *not* to explicitly zero-initialize objects with static linkage.

Comment: It will probably not generate `memset()` because the variable is static.

Comment: @Jens Where did I say assignment?

Comment: You say that the long version (which the question is about) would be your code, which is using assignment. The correct answer is as given by WhozCraig, explicit initialization of all the members.

Answer (score 7):

The long version (and you'll be hard pressed to get longer):

```
static const char vid[25][100] =
{
    {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'},
    {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'},
    {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'},
    {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'},
    {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'},
    {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'},
    {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'},
    {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'},
    {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'},
    {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'},
    {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'},
    {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'},
    {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'},
    {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'},
    {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'},
    {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'},
    {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'},
    {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'},
    {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'},
    {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'},
    {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'},
    {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'},
    {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'},
    {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'},
    {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'}
};
```

That said, the decl is static and therefore is placed in zero-initialized memory to begin with, so this is all somewhat redundant, but at least you know what it looks like.

Comment: Replacing all `0` with `'\0'` would make it considerably longer... But nice effort!

Comment: +1 for the effort, but wait did anybody check if this is correct :)

Comment: another idea to make this longer, use designated initializers: `{ [0] = { [0] = 0, [1] = 0, [2] = 0 ... } ... }`

Comment: @JensGustedt Its correct. 25 rows of 100 elements each =P, and I love the idea of index initializers. Wasn't that a feature add in C99?

Comment: @WhozCraig, yes this was added in C99 and remained in C11, so it is valid C.

Comment: After thinking about this some more I agree with you that this is actually the answer that best reflects what `{0}` is shorthand for.

Comment: Well I suppose that writing out the array with NULL would be the long version.

Answer (score 6):

The standard does not define how the zero'ing is done so it's implementation specific. In practice, for local variables compilers generally generate a `memset`/`RtlZeroMemory`/etc. for this. For static/globals no code is required because the variable will be placed into zero initialised memory.

Comment: I quoted from the same article in my comment above. Of course code is needed to zero the memory - the instructions are executed by the loader, when it sets aside (based on instructions in the executable) the .bss block and ensures that its content is zero. Clock cycles are used. Instructions are carried out. By my definition that is code. Just not code the end user had to write. The memory doesn't "just know". IT IS TOLD.

Comment: I see your argument now. If I wanted to be pedantic and argue for the sake of it I might say that .bss is often implemented with copy-on-write pages so the memory might never even be allocated unless touched.

Comment: Glad we are on approximately the same page now. The COW argument is interesting a bit far fetched - especially for a 250 element array. As you recognized in your comment.

Answer (score 3):

It initializes all the elements of the array to 0 in one go.Else you can imagine the strain doing it individually for all of them.

Comment: "all in one go"? How clever. I thought memory was accessed sequentially.

Comment: @EdS. What I meant is the user(Chad) can initialize all the elements to 0 without having to write a lot of code for that purpose,ie, "in one go".I was not explaining to him how it is done internally.In fact,the user(Chad) didn't even ask for how it is done internally.If he is a beginner,statements like O(1) would only freak him more over a question this simple.

Comment: @Floris I used "In one go" in the context of the user.That is, all he has to do is use ={0} and bingo, all elements are initialized to 0 "at once".I didn't mean all memory is accessed at once just like that.Hope you got what I am trying to say.

Comment: I get it. Just using the `static` keyword is actually all the code needed. But if you have a large block, it will take many clock cycles to be set to zero - that was the only point I was trying to make.

Comment: @Floris Yeah indeed, static storage class initializes to 0 by default.But let me see what you and Mike Kwan were debating about.

Answer (score -1):

"Approximayely" the "really long" version of what you are doing is:

```
static char vid[25][100];
static firstTime = 1;

if(firstTime) {
  int ii, jj;

  for(ii = 0; i < 25; ii++) {
    for (jj = 0; jj < 100; jj++) {
      vid[ii][jj] = 0;
    }
  }
  firstTime = 0;
}
```

This takes account of the fact that this should only be done the very first time, since the variable is declared as `static`. In reality, as pointed out in the comments, the `static` keyword implies initialization to zero, and mapping into a special area called the `.bss` segment. This gets set to zero by the program loader, or some other mechanism, before `main()` is even called. Thus the code that is run doesn't look much like the above  (zeroing blocks of memory can be done quite efficiently on most processors and doesn't involve looping over multiple dimensions!).

## But:

Initialization is something that happens before the `main` function is called, while my "approximately equivalent" code actually is run during execution; so, as Jens pointed out, it is not really the same thing. WhozCraig actually shows the explicit initiozation for which `{0}` is shorthand; it is the best answer.

Comment: This is simply wrong. Static means it is zero initialised already and there is no runtime cost.

Comment: @Mike - OP was asking for an explanation of what is actually happening. I thought this explained that the compiler sets the memory locations used by the static array to zero the first time the code is called. The zeroing happens... even if you don't include the `= {0}`. But if you think about it - when the compiler decides to set aside a chunk of memory for the static array, it DOES have to loop through and set elements to zero. Otherwise there is no way of making sure that it is, in fact, zero. The command that is used may not look much like the above loop, and you never see it...

Comment: From Wikipedia entry on .bss: "Typically, the program loader initializes the memory allocated for the bss section when it loads the program. Operating systems may use a technique called zero-fill-on-demand to efficiently implement the bss segment (McKusick & Karels 1986). In embedded software, the bss segment is mapped into memory that is initialized to zero by the C run-time system before main() is entered."

Comment: @MikeKwan: How does initialization work?  Is it just magic?  The memory just appears, instantaneously, set to zero, with no need to check?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley - Mike is right to say "no **runtime** cost" as it is the program _loader_ that makes sure the memory is set to zero. But that is a technicality. The processor does execute statements that set memory to zero after you say "I want to run this program" and before the static variable is referenced for the first time.

Comment: @Floris: No, he is not right.  The time spent loading your program is part of your program's runtime.  If your program takes 20 seconds to load, but the actual main function only takes 1 second, and my program takes 1 second to load, but then does the same job in 3 seconds, nobody would argue that your program is faster than mine.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley - fair point. I tried to make the distinction that "run time" starts when `main` is called, but your definition makes more sense. On the whole, I think you and I agree about what actually happens.

Comment: @Jens - I understand your point. The _effect_ of my code (setting all elements of the array to zero at the start of the program) is the same, but I agree that WhozCraig nailed it (and I loved your indexed initializer construct - I didn't know that was valid syntax but will remember!)