# Initializing array in C - execution time

Tags: c, arrays, performance

```
int a[5] = {0};
```

VS

```
typedef struct 
{ 
 int a[5]; 
} ArrStruct; 
ArrStruct arrStruct; 
sizeA = sizeof(arrStruct.a)/sizeof(int);
for (it = 0 ; it < sizeA ; ++it) 
    arrStruct.a[it] = 0;
```

Does initializing by for loop takes more execution time? if so, why?

Comment: `int[5]` is only 20 bytes, why would you even care?

Comment: it's for academic purposes...

Answer (score 2):

It depends upon the compiler and the optimization flags.

On recent GCC (e.g. 4.8 or 4.9) with `gcc -O3` (or probably even `-O1` or `-O2`) it should not matter, since the same code would be emitted (GCC has even an optimization which would transform your loop into a `builtin_memset` which would be further optimized).

On some compilers, it could happen that the `int a[5] = {0};` might be faster, because the compiler might emit e.g. vector instruction (or on x86 a `rep stosw`) to clear an array.

The best thing is to examine the generated (gimple representation and) assembler code (e.g. with `gcc -fdump-tree-gimple -O3 -fverbose-asm -mtune=native -S`) and to benchmark. Most of the cases it does not matter. Be sure to enable optimizations when compiling.

Generally, don't care about such micro-optimization; a good optimizing compiler is better than you have time to code.

Comment: Clang produces the exact same assembly output for both under `-O3`.

Comment: Is there any meaning to the fact that with the for loop we have a calculation (it<sizeA) every time. The question is how does the compiler put the value 0 to every element in the array.

Comment: @KobiBurnley Without optimization, yes. The compiler checks the value every loop

Comment: It is also worth noting that, depending on the architecture in use, there may be operations available to the CPU such as zeroing out or setting a large number of bytes (ie: long long words or blocks of them depending on boundary alignment) that is much, much faster than looping through elements. When in doubt, leave it to `memset()`, as the compiler may even further optimize it depending on what's available.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the scope of the variables. For a static or global variable, the first initialization

```
int a[5]={0};
```

may be done at compile time, while the loop is run at, well, run time. Thus there is no "execution" associated with the former.

You may find the discussion of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16096907/1967396) (and in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16096934/1967396) ) interesting.

Comment: I assume you're referring to the fact that a smart compiler will put that global-static array in the `.bss` segment, which is zeroed before the program executes. But the actual zeroing isn't "at compile time". The compiler just says in the object file: "give me this much zeroed memory", and it's the _OS's_ responsibility to actually zero it. Doesn't really affect the answer but I think it's worth thinking about out of interest.

Comment: @Brendan - yes that's what I am talking about. More extensively discussed in the links I included.